# Repeated drive failure/file corruption when switching OSs using bootcamp

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, hdd

I am running BootCamp on a Mid-2012 MacBook Pro running OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 and Windows 10. I have two hard drives in my MBP. The system drive is an SSD, which is partitioned for each of the OSs. My "data" drive is formatted as ExFat so I can easily read/write to the same drive regardless of which operating system I am using. In theory, this works. But multiple times, I have had the hard drive fail when I restart the laptop into Windows mode. The data drive becomes unreadable and Windows says it needs to format it before it can use it. I think it gets corrupted somehow.

Does anyone know why this happens and what I can do to prevent it in the future?

Additional details if they are relevant: one of my programs on my MBP is not quite fully compatible with OS X yet and the only way for me to shut down or restart my MBP is through the terminal (I am updating that so hopefully this variable will be eliminated shortly).

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you certain that the drive is good?  Using terminal, issue the command `diskutil info discX | grep -i smart` where X is the disk number of the drive in question.  Also, why not use the old tried-n-true FAT32?  Do you have files over 4Gb in size?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Allan. Fairly certain... I ran the command, and it says SMART Status is verified. My largest files are between 5 and 6GB. Shouldn't exFat and FAT32 perform equally well, FAT32 file size limitation aside? Is FAT32 somehow more stable?

Lately, I have taken to ejecting the internal drive by right-clicking on it in Finder (even though Disk Utility apparently says that it can't be ejected) prior to resetting in order to run Windows. So far I haven't had the drive failure/file corruption issue again yet.